# Add to has_many through association without finding objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

Here is a typical `has_many :through` association:

```
class Physician < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, through: :appointments
end

class Appointment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
end

class Patient < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, through: :appointments
end
```

#### The Problem

The physician makes 4 appointments with patients: `[1, 2, 3, 4]`

**I can add by finding the users:**

```
user_ids = [1, 2, 3, 4]
users = User.where(id: user_ids)
@physician.patients.push(users)
```

**But I want to add by `ID` directly:**

```
user_ids = [1, 2, 3, 4]
@physician.patients.push(user_ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ids to add:

```
user_ids = [1, 2, 3, 4]
@physician.patient_ids = user_ids
```